# Cleanup utility based on remaining space and oldest files

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a cleaning utility for my RDX.
It would test whether the available space on the tape is less than a certain threshold and erase the oldest files until you reach this threshold.

I tinkered something from bits of code but I can not figure what's wrong :

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for /f "tokens=7" %%a in ('fsutil volume diskfree e:') do set free=%%a
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('"dir e:\*.zip /A-D /OD /B"') do set file=%%b
if %free:~0,-9% lss 61 del e:\%file% else exit
```

Each lines seems to work separately, but not the loop.
Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enableextensions

for /f "tokens=7" %%a in ('fsutil volume diskfree e:') do set "free=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir e:\*.zip /A-D /O-D /B') do set "file=%%b"
if %free:~0,-9% lss 61 (del "e:\%file%") else exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "not the loop" - there are two loops, but you say each line works separately?

Worked quite happily on my machine - so what exactly do you mean?

A few things that may help:

1. The leading `@` merely means 'do not echo this command to the console before it's executed'. Once an `@echo off` instruction is executed, the echoing of commands stops, so the `@` is redundant. It `is` required on the `@echo off` command because otherwise the instruction to turn echoing off would itself be `ECHO`ed.
2. Each `setlocal` starts a new local environment, inheriting all of the current environment variables. Using two is not wrong, it's merely redundant. `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` will suffice. You are not using `delayedexpansion` in this routine, so `that` is itself redundant. The default state of `CMD.EXE` is `enableextensions`. You have to take explicit action to `DISABLE` the extensions - and most batchers will assume the default condition.
3. On my machine, the freespace is the EIGHTH token on the line, not the 7th. This would load `:` into `free` if yours is the same.
4. The double-quotes surrounding the `dir` command are reundant. The command between the SINGLE quotes is executed. Adding the double-quotes does nothing UNLESS there is a single-quote WITHIN the command to be executed.
5. The `IF` comparison could go sadly wrong. Any `%var%` is resolved before the instruction is executed, so should `free` contain fewer than 9 characters, `%free:~0:-9%` would be resolved to [nothing] and the instruction would be executed as `if lss 61...` which would be a syntax-error. Note that in your case, `free` may be `:` and even after correction, of you have less than 1000000000 bytes free, `%free:~0:-9%` would be resolved to nothing and generate the error.
6. If there are no files matching your selection criteria found by the `dir` command, `file` will contain whatever value it had when the batch was started. In all probability, the variable `file` would never have been set, but suppose it was set to `myveryimportantfile` ? For this reason, it's best to make sure that any variables used in a batch are initialised.

So - revised:

```
@echo off
setlocal

FOR %%I IN (free file) DO SET "%%I="
for /f "tokens=8" %%a in ('fsutil volume diskfree e:') do set free=%%a
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir e:\*.zip /A-D /OD /B') do set file=%%b
IF NOT DEFINED FILE EXIT
SET "FREE=%FREE:~0,-9%"
IF NOT DEFINED FREE SET /A FREE=0
if %FREE% lss 61 del "e:\%file%"
```

(Case is redundant - changes in CAPS. Case of metavariables FOR `%%x` is significant)

Note that strictly speaking, even the SETLOCAL is redundant, but it does ensure that this batch does NOT affect the state of the environment after it has terminated.

The syntax `SET "var=somethingorevennothing"` is significant. A simple `SET` statement is aimed at STRINGS, so SPACES are significant. If a space occurs BEFORE the `=` then it is **INCLUDED** in the variable name being set. If there are spaces at the end of the line, they are also included. Quoting the SET overcomes the second problem. Vigilance overcomes the first.

`SET /A` ignores these spaces, but can only be used to set NUMERIC values. The numeric values are in fact stored as a STRING.

HTH

Comment: On my machine, the freespace is the fifth token :)

Comment: Personally, i"d prefer `tokens=2delims=:` which should be language-independent but leave `free` with an easily-overcome leading space.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the Peter's comments, your problem is not looping in the second FOR

Read `HELP FOR` and then you'd try something like this...

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('"dir e:\*.zip /A-D /OD /B"') do (
  set file=%%b
  if %free:~0,-9% lss 61 del e:\%file%
)
```

but, wait, here be more problems: %free% is not refreshed after the deletion; the comparison might be incorrect; the variable %file% does not get updated on each loop iteration... those are probably subject for other SO questions.